# STM32 F103 UART callback works only once

Tags: callback, stm32, uart, hal

I'm using UART RX callback code from here https://www.programmersought.com/article/68737014549/

Looks like this non-blocking RX processing doesn't work in background as expected

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 2 */
HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, (uint8_t *)aRxBuffer1, RXBUFFERSIZE); //This function will turn on the receive interrupt: flag bit UART_IT_RXNE, and set the receive buffer and the maximum amount of data received by the receive buffer */

__HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart1, UART_IT_RXNE);
/* USER CODE END USART1_Init 2 */
```

I receive only once and can't process next incoming bytes, because RX buffer keeps only old value.

Is it something with example or HAL's issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you using DMA mode you must select circular buffer instead of normal buffer to refresh it on receiving new data.

Answer (score 0):

`HAL_UART_Receive_IT()` arms the RX interrupt only once. This is the expected behavior. You need to call it again to re-arm the receiver, after you are done processing the receive buffer.

Answer (score 0):

`HAL_UART_Receive_IT()` Called only once. If you want to receive data continuously after the call, you must call the function again

`main()`

```
.....
HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, &temp_rx, 1);
.....
```

`void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)`

```
// USART2 Rx Interrupt
if (huart->Instance == USART2) {
    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, &temp_rx, 1);
}
```